# Installing tiny_tds gem on Ubuntu 20.04 fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tiny-tds, ubuntu-20.04

I want to insall tiny_tds on Ubuntu 20.04, so I do

```
apt install freetds-dev
```

and the install the gem

```
gem install tiny_tds
```

Works like a charm on Ubuntu 18.04, but 20.04 fails. the last lines of the output are:

```
current directory: /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.2/ext/tiny_tds
make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/bin/mkdir: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:202: .sitearchdir.-.tiny_tds.time] Error 127

make install failed, exit code 2
```

Any ideas on how to work around this?
I have Ubuntu 20.04, RVM with Ruby 2.7 active.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem installing gems on Ubuntu 20.04. with RVM und Ruby 2.7.
As stated, the make process could not find the `mkdir` command.

```
$ which mkdir
/bin/mkdir
```

Since the process is searching for the command in `/usr/bin/mkdir` it cannot be found. I could fix this by creating a symbolic link to the correct path:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/mkdir /usr/bin/mkdir
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Had same issue with gem install pg. So probably not a tiny_tds or pg  related issue but points towards the gem install command.

Comment: This seems suboptimal given that `rvm` + `mkmf` should be able to use `mkdir` from the proper location.  This problem can happen in external native extension builds when `create_makefile` is creating a `Makefile` with `MKDIR_P` or `MAKEDIRS = /usr/bin/mkdir -p` on a system where `mkdir` is provided by a different `PATH` directory: `/bin/mkdir` instead.  The issue can be resolved by fixing the `RbConfig::CONFIG` keys: `MAKEDIRS`, and `MKDIR_P`.  Check yours with: `ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG'`

Answer (score 3):

### Problem

This problem can be caused by upgrading your base OS, which may change the default paths for different tools such as `mkdir`.  Normally, most shells follow the [`PATH`](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) to search for an executable. However, when you're installing gems using Ruby & RVM, there is a lot going on behind the scenes for [compiling "native extensions"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31202707/645491).  Traditionally many Unix, Linux & BSD (*nix) C / C++ projects will follow the standard `./configure && make && make install` pattern.  The `./configure` script generally detect details about the system at build-time, then auto-generate a `Makefile` catered to that particular system.  On GNU systems, the [`autotools`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) maintainer tools are used to also auto-generate a POSIX compatible `./configure` script, and `Makefile.in` template that can be used by `./configure` to generate the final `Makefile`.

When `gem install` or `bundle install` needs to compile a native C / C++ extension for something, it also generates a `Makefile` with system-specific details.  In this example, it's found that `mkdir` utility should be located at `/usr/bin/mkdir`.

As part of this process, the `mkmkf` gem is automatically generating a `Makefile`, usually from an `extconf.rb` script with a configuration matching your system, from `RbConfig::CONFIG`.  However, in this case, the `mkdir` utility is actually located at `/bin/mkdir`.  So, the `RbConfig::CONFIG` settings are now incorrect for your system.  This probably happened because you upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, but had old rubies installed to `~/.rvm` already pre-configured for the older OS release.

So, this is caused by having incorrect `RbConfig::CONFIG` keys.  In this case: `MKDIR_P` or `MAKEDIRS`.

### Solution (Quick Hack Method)

Sometimes you just need a quick hack to fix a tool's path.  This can work in a lot of cases, but sometimes can cause issues when your base OS has changed a lot.  In cases like that, use the full clean & reinstall method below.

1. Find your current `rbconfig.rb` file using RVM:

   ```
    find ~/.rvm/rubies/$(rvm current | cut -d@ -f1) -iname 'rbconfig.rb'
   ```
2. Edit the file and fix the `MKDIR_P` and `MAKEDIRS` keys on the `RbConfig::CONFIG` object:

   ```
    # Your path may be different.  Use the one you found from Step #1
    $EDITOR ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
    # Now change the lines:
      CONFIG["MAKEDIRS"] = "/usr/bin/mkdir -p"
      CONFIG["MKDIR_P"] = "/usr/bin/mkdir -p"
    # To:
      CONFIG["MAKEDIRS"] = "/bin/mkdir -p"
      CONFIG["MKDIR_P"] = "/bin/mkdir -p"
   ```
3. Save the file and retry your `gem install` command:

   ```
    gem install tiny_tds
   ```

### Solution (Full Clean Reinstall Method)

Generally, editing `rbconfig.rb` by hand is not recommended because it's generated from the `./configure` script when compiling Ruby itself.  There are a lot of `RbConfig::CONFIG` keys & values which means there is a lot that could go wrong.  For example:  If some core system libraries changed places or versions, you'll probably run into problems related to linking against those old base OS libraries.  In cases like this, it's best to just reinstall a ruby compiled against your base OS.

1. Re-install your ruby

   ```
    # -j $(nproc) is optional... but can speed up your build by using multiple CPU cores.
    # If you don't have the 'nproc' tool, just pass the number of CPU cores to `-j`
    rvm reinstall --disable-binary  $(rvm current | cut -d@ -f1) -j $(nproc)
   ```
2. Retry your `gem install` command:

   ```
    gem install tiny_tds
   ```